# Anaconda Python Environment Package Conflicts

Tags: python, anaconda, package

I'm at the end of my rope with trying to figure out some python environment issues.  I've created a clean environment with `conda create --no-default-packages --name env_novers python=3.8.5`. Once this environment is activated, `conda list` returns

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ca-certificates           2022.4.26            haa95532_0
certifi                   2022.5.18.1      py38haa95532_0
openssl                   1.1.1o               h2bbff1b_0
pip                       21.2.2           py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.5                h5fd99cc_1
setuptools                61.2.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.38.3               h2bbff1b_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
```

Then I executed `conda env update --name env_novers --file .\environment_novers.yml` with the file at the bottom of this post. This throws pages and pages of conflicts which are incomprehensible to me. Not only is this a "clean" environment, but the update file does not specify any versions. Ultimately, of course, I do intend to specify some version minimums, but have iterated to this no-version file (hence the name!) trying to debug conflicts. The biggest hurdle for me is that the conflicts seem to make no sense. For example, see one chosen at random here:

```
Package cryptography conflicts for:
urllib3 -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4']
urllib3 -> pyopenssl[version='>=0.14'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3|>=1.9|>=2.1.4|>=2.2.1|>=2.8|>=3.3|>=35.0|>=3.2']
```

I read this as specifying that urllib3 requires crypto>=1.3.4 and that pyopenssl requires (with a bunch of ORs) crypto>=1.3. So then if conda installs crypto 1.3.4, all requirements are met. Where's the conflict?

I have already installed (on Win 64) the latest anaconda and run the complete conda update. I tried all this without even specifying python 3.8.5, and get the same thing. Disabling channel priority also does not seem to change anything. Help please!

**environment_novers.yml**

```
channels:
  - pytorch
  - plotly
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - boto3
  - certifi
  - chart-studio
  - dash
  - dask
  - dask-ml
  - dbfread
  - dvc=2.1.0 # version required for backwards compatibility
  - geopandas
  - ipdb
  - ipython
  - ipywidgets
  - joblib
  - jupyter
  - jupyterlab
  - matplotlib
  - nodejs
  - numpy
  - openpyxl
  - pandas
  - pip
  - plotly
  - pyinstaller
  #- python=3.8.5 # python version pinned
  - python-dateutil
  - pytorch
  - regex
  - requests
  - scipy
  - seaborn
  - sqlalchemy
  - statsmodels
  - urllib3
  - pip:
    - geopy
    - pandas-profiling
    - scikit-learn
    - tensorflow
    - xlrd
```

Comment: What is your operating system? With mamba I get no issue in solving the yml you have provided, have you tried that? Also: Why do you install the last 5 libraries with `pip`. I would highly recommend to install them with `conda` as well

Comment: Windows 10 OS; the last 5 are installed with pip as they're not available in the default or conda-forge channels. My question is specifically about using anaconda to setup this environment.

Answer (score 0):

The default solver of `conda` seems too slow to solve this environment/unable to solve it. I would suggest you run

```
conda install libmamba
```

in your base env and then try to solve this environment again. I would also suggest that you move

```
    - geopy
    - pandas-profiling
    - tensorflow
    - scikit-learn
    - xlrd
```

to the `conda` installed packages in your file and create the environment using all specifications:

File env.yml

```
name: env_novers 
channels:
  - pytorch
  - plotly
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - boto3
  - certifi
  - chart-studio
  - dash
  - dask
  - dask-ml
  - dbfread
  - dvc=2.1.0 # version required for backwards compatibility
  - geopandas
  - ipdb
  - ipython
  - ipywidgets
  - joblib
  - jupyter
  - jupyterlab
  - matplotlib
  - nodejs
  - numpy
  - openpyxl
  - pandas
  - pip
  - plotly
  - pyinstaller
  - python=3.8.5 # python version pinned
  - python-dateutil
  - pytorch
  - regex
  - requests
  - scipy
  - seaborn
  - sqlalchemy
  - statsmodels
  - urllib3
  - geopy
  - pandas-profiling
  - scikit-learn
  - xlrd
  - tensorflow
```

Create environment with `conda env create -f env.yml`

Alternatively, you could consider using `mamba`:

```
conda install mamba
mamba env create -f env.yml
```

Comment: The last items are pip-installed by necessity - they're not available from anaconda, as I've already mentioned. Anyway, removing them makes no difference. Even with libmamba installed, I still get conflicts. Further, my question is specifically about using Anaconda and figuring out these seemingly nonsensical conflicts - not using mamba.

Comment: You probably mean that you want to use `conda` specifically for the installation? Do you get an error even when you have libmamba and create the environment using the file I have mentioned? For the last packages, they are all available: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/geopy https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas-profiling https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/scikit-learn https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xlrd

Comment: Yes, since the issues are coming up with Anaconda, which is my team's distribution of choice, I want to solve the issue using it. Even with libmamba installed, and even with changing the source on those last few packages, the conflicts are still showing.